# How make android edittext hint center and left cursor

Tags: android, android-edittext

How set hint text in the center of EditText and set cursor in the left part of EditText? And when i start input text it start from the center EditText?

[image]

Now i have

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/line_white"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/loginEmailField"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:autoText="false"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Choose an email adress"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textColorHint="#9377ab"
                    android:textSize="19sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

thats a bit of a stupid issue, i know.. 
easiest way to solve this is (and keep centered text) is using this simple hack:

```
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s != null && s.toString().length() > 0){
                editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            }else{
                editText.setGravity(Gravity.START);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: That should be the validated answer.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced to the same problem and think of 2 possible variants:

**1. Pretty simple**
Cursor in the middle of the hint looks little unpleasantly.
So i just remove hint whet editText gets focus and set it back otherwise:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        editText.setHint(hasFocus ? "" : "My hint");
    }
});
```

**2. Some hardcode**
In this case:
if editText is empty:
- set text to hint
- set textColor to hintColor
- disable text selecting
- set selection before text (`setSelection(0)`)

if user enters any symbol
- replace hint with ""
- set textColor back to textColor
- enable text selecting

Steps:
2.1 Add TextWatcher

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { // empty }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { // empty }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
        processChangedText(s); 
    }
});
```

2.2 Set on focus change listener:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
       if (hasFocus) {
           processChangedText(editText.getText());
       }
    }
});
```

2.3 And a little magic inside method `processChangedText(Editable s)`

```
private void processChangedText(Editable s) {
    String str = s.toString();
    final int colorHint = ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.color_hint);
    final int colorText = ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.color_text);

    String hint = getString(R.string.login_login_edit_hint);
    if (str.equals(hint)) {
        editText.setTextColor(colorHint);
        enableCursorMove(editText, false);
        editText.setSelection(0);
        return;
    } else {
        editText.setTextColor(colorText);
        enableCursorMove(editText, true);
    }
    if (str.isEmpty()) {
        editText.setText(hint);
    } else if (str.contains(hint)) {
        editText.setText(str.replace(hint, ""));
    } else if (str.length() == 1) {
        editText.setSelection(1);
    }
}
```

2.4 Enabler/disabler cursor move method (probably not a good choice, it's better to create own EditText overriding onSelectionChanged method)

```
private void enableCursorMove(EditText editText, boolean enable) {
    editText.setOnTouchListener(enable ? null : new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            editText.setSelection(0);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

*P.S. I really advise you to use first variant, it's quite simple and looks pretty good.*

Answer (score 3):

You can hide hint when `EditText` get focused.
Use my custom `EditText`:
https://gist.github.com/repitch/2ca5b01a842609cfe26f3a41f825a300

```
public class HintHideEditText extends EditText {

    private CharSequence savedHint;

    public HintHideEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public HintHideEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public HintHideEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        validateHint(focused);
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    }

    public CharSequence getSavedHint() {
        return savedHint;
    }

    public void setSavedHint(CharSequence savedHint) {
        this.savedHint = savedHint;
        validateHint(hasFocus());
    }

    public void setSavedHint(@StringRes int resid) {
        setSavedHint(getContext().getResources().getText(resid));
    }

    private void validateHint(boolean focused) {
        if (focused) {
            savedHint = getHint();
        }
        setHint(focused ? "" : savedHint);
    }

}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14320585)

Comment: @0x0nosugar, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Place the following in your code once you inflated the view:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginEmailField);
editText.setSelection(0);
```

It will place the caret at the beginning of your hint text. Once you start typing the text will keep being centered and the caret will move at the end of what you're typing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of doing it but you can give it a try using following code

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="You text here"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Give underline background to parent framelayout and on its click bring focus on editext

Comment: I said give it a try that does not mean you should down vote somebody

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the edit text's hint:

1. Add a transparency to your EditText's background colour
2. Add a new TextView directly behind your EditText - set it's text to the hint's text.
3. Set `gravity="left"` in you EditText - this way the cursor will be located at the left side of the view.

Place both views (EditText and the TextView) inside a RelativeLayout - this way you can position the hint view behind the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional `View` bellow edit text to simulate edit text line, set edit text background to `null`, and width to `wrap_content`, and `layout_gravity` to center.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@null"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:ellipsize="start" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the xml,the `EditText` must have `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.

Then, set the code like this:

```
final EditText msgTxt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtTxt);

msgTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(s.length() != 0){
            msgTxt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        }
        else{
            msgTxt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this my code:

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
```